# Erro: argument of type char is incompatible with lpcwstr

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

DWORD getbaseadress(DWORD Pid, TCHAR* n);
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    HWND hwnd = 0;
    DWORD pid = 0;

    hwnd = FindWindow(0,"PXG Cliente"); // erro aqui
    if (hwnd)
    {
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
        if (pid)
        {
            HANDLE ghandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, pid);
            if (ghandle)
            {
                DWORD baseadress = getbaseadress(pid, "pxgcliente.exe");// ERRO AQUI
```

Está dando o seguinte erro:

> argument of type char is incompatible with lpcwstr

Como resolver?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

A função está pedindo uma *string multibyte* então use `L"PXG Cliente"`.

Eu aproveitaria e usaria a [`FindWindowEx()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowexa?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que é mais moderna. Deve estar usando várias coisas legadas nesse código.

Comment: Obrigado pela força :)